# HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException is new offen error in my Grails 3 application

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

After update from Grails 2 to Grails 3 of my old app quite often I see in logs HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException exceptiopns like:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.Stale
StateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:283)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:704)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:290)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:230)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:116)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:241)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:158)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.xxx.MyDomain.save(MyDomain.groovy)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3132)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3011)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3391)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.flushSession(A
```

It happens not very often in different places during a flush.
Transactions used. Looks like problem with update of other entities during flushing

What is the reason for it? How to detect, what entity modification is wrong? Can it be caused by long transaction processing time?

- Grails 3.2.9
- Mysql DB
- Grails 2 app Hibernate version: 4.3.8.1
- Grails 3 app Hibernate version: 5.1.3

Comment: What version of Hibernate were you using in Grails 2 and what version are you using now in Grails 3?

Comment: @bassmartin Hibernate 4.3.8.1  -> 5.1.3

Comment: I suggest you try with Hibernate 4. You can still choose to use Hibernate 4 with Grails 3.

Comment: @bassmartin no way to downgrade. =) I want to know, what is the reason for this exception and how to get additional information